# remove image icon in jbutton

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, imageicon

I have a selectpic() method to set images in the jbuttons.

```
public void selectpic() {
    rule rule = new rule();
    rule.shuffle();
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        if (rule.pic[i] == 0) {
            Icon0.setImage(Icon0.getImage().getScaledInstance(WIDTH,HEIGHT,Image.SCALE_DEFAULT));
            panel1.add(new JButton(Icon0));
        } else if (rule.pic[i] == 1) {
            Icon1.setImage(Icon1.getImage().getScaledInstance(WIDTH,HEIGHT,Image.SCALE_DEFAULT));
            panel1.add(new JButton(Icon1));
        } else if (rule.pic[i] == 2) {
            Icon2.setImage(Icon2.getImage().getScaledInstance(WIDTH,HEIGHT,Image.SCALE_DEFAULT));
            panel1.add(new JButton(Icon2));
        } else if (rule.pic[i] == 3) {
            Icon3.setImage(Icon3.getImage().getScaledInstance(WIDTH,HEIGHT,Image.SCALE_DEFAULT));
            panel1.add(new JButton(Icon3));
        } else if (rule.pic[i] == 4) {
            Icon4.setImage(Icon4.getImage().getScaledInstance(WIDTH,HEIGHT,Image.SCALE_DEFAULT));
            panel1.add(new JButton(Icon4));
        } else if (rule.pic[i] == 5) {
            Icon5.setImage(Icon5.getImage().getScaledInstance(WIDTH,HEIGHT,Image.SCALE_DEFAULT));
            panel1.add(new JButton(Icon5));
        } 
    }
}
```

When each round is finished i have to call the selectpic() method again to change images.

However, i can't just simply call that method again to do it.

Q1. Is it necessary to remove the images first and then call the selectpic() again, so that it can change the images?

Q2. If so, i searched in forum and found using

```
xxxx.setImage(null);
```

can remove the image(xxxx is the name of that jbutton),

but in the selectpic(), i use this to add the jbuttons.

```
panel1.add(new JButton(Icon0));
```

how can i know the name of the jbuttons so that i can use xxxx.setImage(null); to remove the images first?

Thanks!!

Comment: selectPic is not a good method as it should only concern itself with setting icons on already existing JButtons and nothing more. It should not be adding JButtons to the GUI. Edit: as Emd4600 recommends. 1+ to his answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not keeping track of your JButtons, and calling `selectpic()` fills the JPanel with buttons, so calling it multiple times will create a lot of buttons.

I recommend you to have your JButtons in the class fields, like this:

```
private JButton button1;
```

Then, when you initialize your UI, initialize your buttons too:

```
// UI init here
button1 = new JButton();
panel1.add(button1);
```

And in the `selectpic` method, set your icons.

```
button1.setIcon(choosedIcon);
```

PD: Now I look more carefully to your code, an array of JButtons would be better, I think. So, the field declaration would be this:

```
private JButton[] buttons = new JButton[numberOfButtons];
```

The initalization would be something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfButtons; i++) {
    buttons[i] = new JButton();
    panel1.add(buttons[i]);
}
```

And for setting the icon,

```
buttons[i].setIcon(chosedIcon);
```

PD2: I recommend you to start your variable names with a lowercase letter, like in the [`Naming Convention`](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html).

Comment: And start class names with upper case letters. i.e., `rule rule = new rule();` should be `Rule rule = new Rule();`. 1+ to this answer.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. At first I really want to declare  JButtons 1- 9. but if i do so i am not able to write the program in order to set the correct images in the certain jbuttons using for loop....

Comment: here is the pic[] : 
int pic[] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16,
   17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26 };
acutually the selectpic() extends to "else if (rule.pic[i] == 26)....."
after shuffle, i get the first 9 numbers in the pic[] and use the for loop in selectpic() to set the corresponding images in the jbuttons.

Comment: Then you might want to use an array of `JButton`s instead. Look at the answer again, I've edited it.